# Getting Error: 'couldnt normalize path' when rendering mapview using leaflet package in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet, r-mapview

I have build a Shiny App with one tab containing a map with points that can be analyzed in other tabs.
I build this map using `leaflet`, but since my version of the map does exactly the same as the `mapview` package, i want to incorporate this in the app instead of the longer code using pure `leaflet`.

What i need: A map on which the user can select a base map (earth, open topo whatever) on which points containing data are projected. When hovering over the points, raw data is visible. I.e. Exactly what `mapview` does.

My spatial points are loaded using the `sf` package and work fine when using `mapview` outside of the `shiny` environment.

I tried to incorporate the mapview using this stack-question: [filtering data reactively to generate maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585109/filtering-data-reactively-to-generate-maps/59585256)

my code:

```
points <- read.sf("points.shp") 

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    
    # TAB I - MAPS
    tabPanel("Maps", fluid = TRUE,
            titlePanel("PQ-locations"),
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
              ),
              mainPanel(fluidRow(leafletOutput("mymap") 
                                
                                 )
                        )
            )
            )
            ))

server <- function(input, output, session){

output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
  mapview(points)@map
 })
}
```

however, i get the following error on the page when launching the app:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7038
Warning: Error in value[[3L]]: Couldn't normalize path in `addResourcePath`, with arguments: `prefix` = 'PopupTable-0.0.1'; `directoryPath` = ''
  [No stack trace available]
```

I don't know what this means and why i get this error. This method of plotting mapview in shiny seems to work fine for other people.

Any help is much appreciated.

using latest versions of packages and R-Studio.

Regards

Comment: See https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/312. Should be fixed if you `devtools::install_github("r-spatial/mapview")`.